# Can RFID reader over wireless send message to my PC or phone?

Tags: wireless, rfid

I have done some basic programming with RFID readers and tags. What I have done till now is, get messages from the reader into my tags, and then connect the tags to the base to read the data collected from the readers.

Now, I want to built a system as follows: When an RFID tag comes near an RFID reader, the reader will receive the tag id, and then over wireless send the tag id along with its own id to a base, which can be a PC or a phone (any device, which can do some processing on the ids).

I am not sure what are the economic and efficient ways to transmit this data over the wireless to the base. Some readings I did till now:

1. I found a few posts talking about scanning RFID tags with phones (iPhone, Android). But it seems the distance between the tags and phones, should be max a few inches. But, I want to the reader and tag to be at least one feet away from each other.
2. I found there are USB enables RFID readers, but again you need to connect it to the base with a wire. SO, not an option for me.
3. Is Bluetooth a viable option? If yes, then the reader and the base should be in the short range or Bluetooth. But they can be far from each other.
4. If I want the Reader to be connected to Wifi, I need a Wifi adapter connected to it. Correct? Is there any reader I can buy and program to send message to the base over the Wifi adapter?

I want the solution to be a cheap one too!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to be useful to you, but...

1) The maximum effective distance between tag and reader is determined by the type of hardware you are using.  If you are using small passive (HF band) RFID tags, the max range is something between a foot or two.  Of course, this is also dependent upon the sensitivity of your RFID reader's receiver.

2) Why is this not an option for you?  You can have an RFID reader hooked up to a repeater and have the repeater transmit the signal via wireless network to your device.  Maybe I do not fully understand the problem you are trying to solve because it is not explained in detail.

3) Bluetooth is only a viable option if you have line-of-sight between transmitter and receiver with a distance < 100 meters for a Class 1 transmitter, < 10 meters for Class 2, and a few centimeters for a Class 3 transmitter.

4) Of course they are. But it all depends on your budget (which was not specified).  Have you looked into Arduino or Raspberry Pi modules?  I am sure they have modules you can use to do this very thing at low cost.

Comment: Yes, attaching a Raspberry Pi to the Reader is a viable option. But I need many readers, each doing a different job. That means, I have to buy a Pi for each reader! That will be very expensive! RPi is a full fledged computer itself. I don't need that much functionality for the Reader. Only a way to transfer data wirelessly.

Comment: I still don't fully understand your problem, but it seems to me that you have two options: get a Pi for each reader, or connect them to a switch and multiplex.  The second option will be more complex than the first one.  In Project Management, there is never a 100% optimal solution. There is going to be a trade-off of some kind.  Only you know what the best solution will be. Remember there are options other than WiFi. But none of us know what your constraints are (budget, schedule, manpower, etc.). At least the Pi will give you a quick and cheap way to prototype what you need.